# tcl-tk: Case insensitive accelerator (or multiple accelerators) for a menu item

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

While creating a menu bar I noticed that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut/accelerator works fine to invoke Save menu but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> with CAPS on) does not invoke the Save menu. Following is the code.

```
$fileMenu add command -label "Save As" -command { saveOperation } -underline 1 -accelerator "Ctrl-s"
```

Is it possible to have a case-insensitive accelerator for a menu item or multiple accelerators for a menu item that capture keypress in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the `-accelerator` option is only a visual component of the menu label. You still have to create a bind for it to do something. So, to create the case insensitive accelerator, you could do something like:

```
$fileMenu add command -label "Save As" -command {saveOperation} \
        -underline 1 -accelerator "Ctrl-s"

# I'm assuming the parent window is where you want the accelerator to work
set w [winfo parent $fileMenu]

bind $w <Control-KeyPress-s> saveOperation  ; # lowercase
bind $w <Control-KeyPress-S> saveOperation  ; # uppercase
```

Comment: Instead of invoking the command in the binding, one can invoke the menu item: `bind $w <Control-S> [list $fileMenu invoke {Save As}]`. Which way is preferable depends on your program structure, but binding to the menu item means that if you disable the menu item, the binding is suppressed (it fires, but has no effect).

Comment: I usually channel both the accelerators and the menu items through an action object (borrowing terminology from Java Swing) that also knows how to turn off and on _all_ the places that are channeled through it. Using a common model always helps keep the GUI's apparent internal complexity down…